# checking the condition in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating app in ionic /angularjs.

The controller fetches the data in JSON format from the URL and displays unique images in div elements. I want to allow these images to be clicked and then display the data according to *offer_name*, which is coming from the JSON data.

e.g.: Suppose I display the image for Amazon (in background *offer_name* is amazon (having 10 records)). When the user clicks on that, it displays all the records related to amazon.

Hope you get my point but no database is included; it only works with JSON data.

Also, how can the check current value be checked in ng-repeat?

Here is my code:

```
.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope,$http) {   
     $http.get("http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;

      /* $scope.stack=[];
      angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(item){

        $scope.stack =item.store_image;
        var uni_img=[];
        for(var i=0 ; i< $scope.stack.length;i++)
        {
            if(uni_img.indexOf($scope.stack[i] == -1))
                uni_img.push($scope.stack[i]);
        }
         console.log(uni_img);
})*/
  });
      $scope.dealopen = function($a){
            for (var i=0;i<$scope.myData.length;i++)
        {
            //console.log($scope.data[i].name);
            $link=$scope.data[i].offer_name;
            if ($link==$a)
            {

            $window.open($link,"_self","location=yes"); 
            console.log($a);
            }
        }       
        }        
})
```

Html

```
<div class="item col-sm-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 " ng-repeat="da in myData | unique: 'store_image'" >
    <div class="thumbnail">                   
        <img class="thumbnail  img-responsive " ng-src="{{ da.store_image}}"     
                    />   
         <div class="caption">
            <b class="group inner list-group-item-heading center-block">
            {{da.offer_name | limitTo: 12 }} Deals</b>                           
            <a class="item item-text-wrap" ng-href="#/Deals/{{da.offer_name}}">View Deal</a>    
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is the output:

[image: myOutput].

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your JSON file?

Comment: check the url http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) to execute javascript (e.g. inline or call a function in the controller scope. Per the documentation for [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) *$index* can be referenced for the current index:

> Special properties are exposed on the local scope of each template instance, including:
>
> ```
> +----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Variable |  Type   |                                   Details                                   |
> +----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | $index   | number  | iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)                       |
> | $first   | boolean | true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.                      |
> | $middle  | boolean | true if the repeated element is between the first and last in the iterator. |
> | $last    | boolean | true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.                       |
> | $even    | boolean | true if the iterator position $index is even (otherwise false).             |
> | $odd     | boolean | true if the iterator position $index is odd (otherwise false).              |
> +----------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```
>
> <sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)</sup>

So the *image* tag can have the attribute *ng-click* to utilize that directive, like this:

```
    <img class="thumbnail  img-responsive " ng-src="{{ da.store_image}}" ng-click="showData(da.offer_name, $index)"/>
```

Then use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter all offers into a filtered array of offers matching the *offer_name*:

```
$scope.showData = function (offer_name, index) {
  $scope.offerName = da.offer_name;
  $scope.filteredOffers = $scope.myData.filter(function(offer) {
    return offer.offer_name == $scope.offerName;
  });
}
```

And then add another set of elements to display the items in *filteredOffers*.

```
<div ng-repeat="offer in filteredOffers">
  <div class="couponCode">{{offer.coupon_code}}</div>
  <div class="couponTitle">{{offer.coupon_title}}</div>
  <div class="couponDescription">{{offer.coupon_Description}}</div>
</div>
```

See the example below where the *showData* function updates the model *selectedIndex*, *offerName* and *filteredOffers* using these components.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui'])
  .controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.offerName = ''; //set initially
      $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
      $scope.filteredOffers = [];

      $http.get("http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8").then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data;
      });
      $scope.showData = function(offer_name, index) {
        $scope.offerName = offer_name;
        $scope.filteredOffers = $scope.myData.filter(function(offer) {
          return offer.offer_name == $scope.offerName;
        });
        $scope.selectedIndex = index;
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.1.5" data-require="angular.js@*" context="anonymous"></script>
<script data-require="angular-ui@*" data-semver="0.4.0" src="//rawgithub.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/master/build/angular-ui.js" context="anonymous"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
  <div>
    OfferName:
    <span ng-bind="offerName"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    selected index:
    <span ng-bind="selectedIndex"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="item col-sm-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 " ng-repeat="da in myData | unique: 'store_image'">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="thumbnail  img-responsive " ng-src="{{ da.store_image}}" ng-click="showData(da.offer_name, $index)" />
      <div class="caption">
        <b class="group inner list-group-item-heading center-block">
            {{da.offer_name | limitTo: 12 }} Deals</b>
        <a class="item item-text-wrap" ng-href="#/Deals/{{da.offer_name}}">View Deal</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div ng-repeat="offer in filteredOffers">
      <div class="couponCode">{{offer.coupon_code}}</div>
      <div class="couponTitle">{{offer.coupon_title}}</div>
      <div class="couponDescription">{{offer.coupon_Description}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)</sup> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: its still not display the result on my deals page .. thanks in advance

Comment: its changing  the index but value is not passing on next page and also not display on that ..

Comment: Offer_name now is coming but it now pass with url and not display on deals page and its a ionic app

Comment: its also display the result but on same page not on deals page kindly update thanks

Comment: i made some change in route now its looks like this -http://localhost:8100/#/Deals/Tatacliq.com%20CPS%20-%20India

Answer (score 0):

At first look you never call the $scope.dealopen function,
may be this can work....

```
<div class="item col-sm-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 " ng-repeat="da in myData | unique: 'store_image'" >
    <div class="thumbnail">                   
        <img class="thumbnail  img-responsive " ng-src="{{ da.store_image}}"/>   
        <div class="caption">
            <b class="group inner list-group-item-heading center-block">{{da.offer_name | limitTo: 12 }} Deals</b>                           
            <a class="item item-text-wrap" ng-click="dealopen(da.offer_name)">View Deal</a>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $index, that is the variable used in agular to know the index position in ng-repeat, if you want to know more about another contro variables of ng-repeat  read the docs in the next link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

An basic example  is.

CONTROLLER

```
    app.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

      $scope.myData = [{path:'http://www.imagefree1.com',info:'http://www.infoimage1.com'},
                       {path:'http://www.imagefree2.com',info:'http://www.infoimage2.com'},
                       {path:'http://www.imagefree3.com',info:'http://www.infoimage3.com'}];

      $scope.callDetail=function(index)

         window.open(myData[index].info);
})
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="image in myData">
   <a href="#" ng-click="callDetail($index)">
      <img src="image.path" alt="Description"/>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: if data come from url